# display like result in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have This Result but I want to display it below in sql server 2008

```
Code    Account Debit_1 Debit_2 Debit_3
1       1/25    286     12750   30000
1       1/25    286     12750   30000
1       1/25    286     12750   30000
```

how can i display this like below

```
Code    Account Debit_1  
1       1/25    286  
1       1/25    12750    
1       1/25    30000
```

Comment: From your question it is not clear what you realy want or what you already tried.. Have a look here, how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hints: `GROUP BY` and `PIVOT`

Answer (score 1):

Use [UNION ALL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
SELECT Code,Account,Debit_1
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Code,Account,Debit_2
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Code,Account,Debit_3
FROM Table1
```

Comment: and how about when there are 200 columns?

Comment: Do `UNION` instead, to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I would unpivit using `cross apply` and `values`:

```
select code, account, debit
from t cross apply
     (values (debit_1), (debit_2), (debit_3)
     ) v(debit);
```

Answer (score 0):

without distinct UNION ALL will gives multiple rows,

SELECT DISTINCT CODE,ACCOUNT,debit_1 from  display_tab
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT CODE,ACCOUNT,debit_2 from  display_tab
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT CODE,ACCOUNT,debit_3 from  display_tab

While UNION gives the distinct rows to automatically

selECT  CODE,ACCOUNT,debit_1 from  display_tab
UNION 
selECT  CODE,ACCOUNT,debit_2 from  display_tab
UNION 
selECT  CODE,ACCOUNT,debit_3 from  display_tab